# When does OnWebSocketClose fire in Jetty 9

Tags: websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a simple embedded Jetty 9 websocket server. I have a method like this in my annotated websocket implementation:

```java
@OnWebSocketClose
void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
    logger.info "Closed connection [${this}]"
    connectionManager.remove(this)
    Event closeEvent = commsEventFactory.buildCloseEvent(this, statusCode, reason)
    eventReceiver.postEvent(closeEvent)
}
```

I have a spock test which connects to the server using async-http-client. I get a successful connection and can send messages back and forth.

However, onClose() is never called (when I call async-http-client's websocket.close() or client.close() or even when the test JVM dies).

I expected the onClose to fire immediately when the far end of the socket disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClose() will fire to indicate that the local side websocket has changed state to closed.

It can result from:

- A proper websocket close handshake has been received by remote endpoint (also known as a clean close)
- Any protocol violation (in parsing or generating) that will attempt to issue a clean close (status code 1002).  Note: due to the nature of this situation, this close might not be a clean close handshake.
- A connection timeout, resulting in an abnormal (non-clean) close. (status code 1006)
- Any read I/O exception on the socket, resulting in an abnormal (non-clean) close. (status code 1006)
- Any write I/O exception on the socket, resulting in an abnormal (non-clean) close. (status code 1006)

Comment: Thanks Joakim! That's definitely my understanding of when onClose should fire. But sadly, not what I've been seeing. I wondered idly whether it was something in the local network on my Mint machine, but I didn't pursue this. I've since moved to using atmosphere, which appears to be working ok.

Comment: You are correct.  There were a few close bugs. [406449](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406449) and [404991](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404911) that were recently [fixed and delivered in Jetty 9.0.3.v20130506](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00049.html) please give that version a try.

Comment: How can I reconnect on OnClose method?

Comment: @Alireza sounds like a good topic for a new question, go ask it!