# reconnect after OnWebSocketClose - jetty 9.4

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, reconnect

According to this post [[When does OnWebSocketClose fire in Jetty 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888533/when-does-onwebsocketclose-fire-in-jetty-9]), `OnClose` fire for me correctly.
but i can not reconnect, because I have not correct situation. (websocett is closed and I can not send any message)

where and when I can reconnect in websocket problem (close by network problem or timeout or kickout by sever after n seconds without handshaking)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have solved this issue but I managed to come up with a solution to reconnect a WebSocket connection.

For my scenario, I would like to reconnect my WebSocket connection if `@OnWebSocketError` method is triggered. Initially I implemented it like this

**Implementation A**:

```
@OnWebSocketError
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    someMethodToReconnect();
}
```

and inside `someMethodToReconnect`

```
if (client == null) {
    client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
    client.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
}

if (socket == null) {
    socket = new ReaderSocket();  // ReaderSocket is the name of my @WebSocket class
}

try {
    client.start();
    client.connect(socket, new URI(socketUrl), request);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Unable to connect to WebSocket: ", e);
}
```

However, this led to another issue. There are 2 types of error thrown back to me **if the server is not up**. The exceptions are `java.net.ConnectException` and `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException`.

The flow would be:

1. Initial request to WebSocket server (server is not up)
2. `java.net.ConnectException` thrown
3. `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException` thrown

And in **Implementation A**, `someMethodToReconnect` would be called twice.

This led to **Implementation B**

```
@OnWebSocketError
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    if (e instanceof ConnectException) {
        // Attempt to reconnect
        someMethodToReconnect();
    } else {
        // Ignore upgrade exception
    }
}
```

So far **Implementation B** works fine, however I'm trying to find out if there's any other exceptions that would be thrown.

Comment: This exactly captured what was happening in my code.  By implementing your solution my reconnects are happening perfectly.

Comment: WARNING: our code was already working so it is ok to hide true Upgrade Exceptions.  But if you get request.setSubProtocols wrong (like I did when I was first coding this way back) it will hide your problems.  Also, I do much more logging around the exception handling in case something someday starts throwing things I don't expect.

Comment: Can you show all code?  Based on what I am looking at your `someMethodToReconnect` exists inside `ReaderSocket`.